# Include Build request user in jenkins mail

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

After a build is finished I use the mail-ext-plugin (Jenkins Email Extension Plugin) to send an email to certain users.
I would like to include the user who started (requested) the build in that mail.
- I couldn't find anything working with the default Jenkins vars.
- I Couldn't find anything in the mail-ext vars.
- I tried Build User Vars Plugin to get $BUILD_USER

but I can't get it to work.

How to get to $BUILD_USER, BUILD_REQUESTER, USERNAME or something like that

For now I have

```
$DEFAULT_CONTENT

--

{$BUILD_USER}
```

resulting in

```
zzz test GreenHat - Build # 27 - Still Failing:
Check console output....

--

{$BUILD_USER}
```

also tried without {}

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have finally found what I wanted,
adding:

```
$CAUSE
```

or

```
${CAUSE}
```

gives

```
Started by user Jan Jansen
```

Answer (score 6):

I realise I'm replying to a 4-year-old question here, but Google brought me here so others may find this information useful...

There have been many [changes](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) to the Email-ext Jenkins plugin over the last few years, which affect this question - for example, in v2.38 (May 24, 2014):

> Implemented new extension point for recipient providers (RecipientProvider) this changes the way that recipient types are added
>
> There are no longer checkboxes for "Requestor" "Recipients" etc, each is provided by an implementation of a RecipientProvider

Using the latest version of the plugin, if you wish to send an email to the user who triggered a build, you can simply select "Requestor" from the "Send To" trigger options:

[image: jenkins screenshot]

The "Recipient List" is a hard-coded list which you can also define for the job.

Comment: not really answering the original question, but useful anyway!

Answer (score 4):

**SIMPLE SOLUTIONS (WITHOUT ANY PLUGINS / NO PLUGINS) !!**

**METHOD 1: Via Shell**

```
BUILD_TRIGGER_BY=$(curl --silent ${BUILD_URL}/api/xml | tr '<' '\n' | egrep '^userId>|^userName>' | sed 's/.*>//g' | sed -e '1s/$/ \//g' | tr '\n' ' ')
echo "BUILD_TRIGGER_BY: ${BUILD_TRIGGER_BY}"
```

**METHOD 2: Via Groovy**

```
node('master') {
BUILD_TRIGGER_BY = sh ( script: "curl --silent ${BUILD_URL}/api/xml | tr '<' '\n' | egrep '^userId>|^userName>' | sed 's/.*>//g' | sed -e '1s/\$/ \\/ /g'", returnStdout: true ).trim()
echo "BUILD_TRIGGER_BY: ${BUILD_TRIGGER_BY}"
}
```

**METHOD 3: Via Groovy**

```
BUILD_TRIGGER_BY = "${currentBuild.getBuildCauses()[0].shortDescription} / ${currentBuild.getBuildCauses()[0].userId}"
echo "BUILD_TRIGGER_BY: ${BUILD_TRIGGER_BY}"
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Started by user Admin / user@example.com
```

**Note**: Output will be both User ID and User Name

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `{$BUILD_USER}` should be `${BUILD_USER}`,
but even this way it will not work unless you install this Plugin:

[**Build User Vars Plugin**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+User+Vars+Plugin)

It gives you the following variables:

- BUILD_USER – full name of user started build,
- BUILD_USER_FIRST_NAME – first name of user started build,
- BUILD_USER_LAST_NAME – last name of user started build,
- BUILD_USER_ID – id of user started build.

(see the plugin page for more details)

Comment: As I stated in my question, I tried Build User Vars Plugin, but I can not get it to work.
Maybe it's not compatible with the mail-ext plugin
`$CAUSE

${BUILD_USER}
{$BUILD_USER}
$BUILD_USER
BUILD_USER`
gives
`Started by user Jan Jansen

${BUILD_USER}
{$BUILD_USER}
$BUILD_USER
BUILD_USER
`