# Include Build request user in jenkins groovy email

Tags: email, groovy, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

After a build is finished I use the mail-ext-plugin (Jenkins Email Extension Plugin) to send an email to certain users. I would like to include the user who started (requested) the build in that email. I have tried the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12835830/include-build-request-user-in-jenkins-mail) however, that didn't seem to work I just got this error.

```
Error in script or template: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: CAUSE for class: SimpleTemplateScript4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much searching I found a page on jelly usage on the Jenkins wiki ([here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Basic+guide+to+Jelly+usage+in+Jenkins)). There is a [link](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/?hudson/model/Descriptor.html) on this page which contains all the useable classes. I was able to  find the cause class and used this great [example](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CD8QFjAC&url=https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/download/attachments/3604514/jenkins-matrix-email-html.template?version=1&modificationDate=1332562186000&ei=2rUAUq-5LNKIhQfo2IDICg&usg=AFQjCNG37Zxl_DdNQsjiBIVD8dFZV4G0Iw&sig2=ArdGKAMSYanM856kZRxi1A&bvm=bv.50310824,d.ZG4) to help me implement it in my code. I added

```
<%
    for (hudson.model.Cause cause : build.causes) {
%>
        ${cause.shortDescription}
<%
    }
%>
```

which produced -

```
Started by user Matthew Armstrong
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Cause for class`, you can try to `import hudson.model.Cause`, or even better - directly call the `currentBuild.getBuildCauses()`, instead of importing 'Cause' class.

For example:

```
String buildUserName = currentBuild.getBuildCauses()[0].userName
String buildDescription = currentBuild.getBuildCauses()[0].shortDescription
```

If the above didn't work, try also:

```
def userCause = currentBuild.getBuildCauses('hudson.model.Cause$UserIdCause')
String buildUserName = userCause.userName[0] ?: "Unknown"
String buildDescription = userCause.shortDescription[0] ?: "Unknown"
```